# Rails paperclip + aws/s3 private access issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am creating a Rails app with the following functionality:

- A user can save images that are saved to S3.
- A user can write text and save it to the database.
- A user can use a saved image to implement in a text.

All the communications with S3 are set to private, so only registered users can access images and documents. I have put the expiring_url(3600) (1hour, just for test).
When I select an image and save it into a text, a database record with the text html is created, with inside the url to the image and his expiring data.

The problem rises when I load this text on a later time: the image won't be visible anymore, because the key has expired.

How can I work around this problem?
A solution would be to lengthen the expire time, but this I think is not the way to go...

Thanks in advance,

Wouter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that lengthen the expire time really is not the way to go. Another approach would be to always point your image url to one of your own application Controller that generates an authenticated url on the fly and then redirects the user request to that url.

The best guide for this that I have found is [thewebfellas.com/blog/2009/8/29/protecting-your-paperclip-downloads](http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2009/8/29/protecting-your-paperclip-downloads)

It covers a lot of different scenarios but I think you would be interested to read from the section "Scaling up to Amazon S3"

Comment: Tanks a lot for this answer. I fixed it following this blog post.

Comment: A more updated guide which includes walkthroughs and source code for Paperclip, CarrierWave, and Refile: https://medium.com/@carlosramireziii/secure-file-download-urls-in-rails-d52128b24311#.tubaua8va